# Validating JSON input message using swagger in IIB

Tags: json, ibm-integration-bus

I'm using IIB v10.0.0.18 and I have an application which its input node is http input and I want to do a validation of the JSON input message received to the http input node against swagger file.
Can anyone please suggest what should be done for validating the input message against the swagger file I have ?

Comment: There is an alternative approach that I saw online => https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/07/18/validating-json-message-in-iib/.......this will definitely work. The idea is to convert the JSON to XML and then use the XML to validate against the corresponding XML schema...let me know if this works for you

Comment: Kingo Mostafa  - were you able to find a solution ?

Comment: Hi Rohan,
sorry, did not notice your reply before.
Actually, I have implemented it the same way advised by Kimbert in his answer below.
I used a Java class into a shared library with a function that does the validation and then by calling this Java function from esql file, I was able to do the validation.

Answer (score 2):

IIB does not yet support validation of JSON because until recently, the JSON schema standard was not very mature. App Connect Enterprise (the latest version of IIB) might offer JSON validation at some point in the future.

For now, the best option would be to use a JavaCompute node to call one of the Java-based JSON parsers. I strongly recommend that you putt the Java classes into a shared library, and use the library-specific classloader feature in IIBv10. This is much easier than deploying the JAR files manually.

Comment: Thanks Kimbert for your reply, but I do not want to parse the json input message, I just want to validate it against the swagger file I have to do an action in case the validation succeeded and do another action in case the validation failed.

Comment: Technically, to validate a message against a schema you must parse the message in full. You may not want an IIB message tree, but that's OK - you will not get a message tree if you just send the input JSON to a Java class library for validation.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of App Connect Enterprise (new name for IIB) is v12 and includes a validating JSON parser, which can validate against JSON schema or Swagger / OpenAPI definition.